# How to animate animal mouth and eyes from a photo

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence

In android I need to animate the mouth and eyes from a photo. I need to create an app like [my talking pet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.wobamedia.mytalkingpet.free)  just with the very basic feature.

Is there any library available that can do this ?

Or I have to train a custom model to get the face landmarks of dog or cat and move the landmark pixels accordingly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link for more information related to detect the face landmarks in android. They have cleared all concept related to face detection.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/detect-faces

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have checked this link but it only detects human faces not animals.